# foreach multiple times and display two arrays

Tags: c#

I need some help in foreach:

my code:

```
var Content = "nickname:Steven ID:01 nickname:pascal ID:02 nickname:nils ID:03";
            var v = Content.Split().Where(l => l.StartsWith("nickname:")).ToList();
            var c = Content.Split().Where(l => l.StartsWith("ID:")).ToList();
            for(int i = 0; i < v.Count(); i++)
            {
                var x = v[i];
                foreach (var o in c)
                {
                    var b = o;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(x + " - " + b);
                }
            }
```

Output:

```
nickname:Steven - ID:01
nickname:Steven - ID:02
nickname:Steven - ID:03
nickname:pascal - ID:01
nickname:pascal - ID:02
nickname:pascal - ID:03
nickname:nils - ID:01
nickname:nils - ID:02
nickname:nils - ID:03
```

I want only display the nickname and the ID but something is wrong..
I dont know how I can fix this.

best regards

Comment: You should look at a regex pattern => `(nickname:(\w+)\s+ID:(\d+))`. Tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/naB0OS/1)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a regex alternative,

```
var Content = "nickname:Steven ID:01 nickname:pascal ID:02 nickname:nils ID:03";
var list = Regex.Matches(Content, @"nickname:(.+?)\s+ID:(\d+)")
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => new
            {
                Name = m.Groups[1].Value,
                ID = m.Groups[2].Value
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: How do I add this now to listbox?

Comment: @FreddyGerogin You have a list of `Name,ID` pairs and you don't know how add them to a listbox? Have you tried anything before commenting?

Comment: I have tried many but this dont works, listbox1.items.add(list);

Comment: Those *"many ways"* seem missing a simple loop. As I said, it is a list. `foreach(var x in list) listbox1.Items.Add(x.Name + "-" + x.ID);`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two loops, that's why it is giving the result you don't want. 
Remember, Inner loop runs completely for each value of outer loop

I have corrected the code for you:

```
var Content = "nickname:Steven ID:01 nickname:pascal ID:02 nickname:nils ID:03";
        var v = Content.Split().Where(l => l.StartsWith("nickname:")).ToList();
        var c = Content.Split().Where(l => l.StartsWith("ID:")).ToList();
            for(int i = 0; i < v.Count(); i++)
            {
                var x = v[i];
                var ids = c[i];
                Console.Write(x.ToString() + " - ");
                Console.WriteLine(ids.ToString());

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var Content = "nickname:Steven ID:01 nickname:pascal ID:02 nickname:nils ID:03";
var strs=Content.Split(' ');
for(int i = 0; i < strs.Count(); i+=2)
{
var name = strs[i].Split(':')[1];
var id = strs[i+1].Split(':')[1];
Console.WriteLine(name + " - " + id);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is only with how you loop. Below is how you can correctly loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.Count(); i++)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(v[i] + " - " + c[i]);
}
```